# How can I get the isConnected state for MetaMask in JS?

Tags: javascript, metamask

I'm trying to get the state for isConnected in plain JS to return true/false if the user's MetaMask is connected or not to my website. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
  const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
  const account = accounts[0];
```

Here you can get the address of the user if connected!